# unable to parse regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I've some data and I want to extract some details from it.

```
<div id="ctl00_hpVendorManager">
<h5 class="panelTitle"><span class="title ">Vendor Manager(s)</span></h5>
Resource Manager: CHS MSP HOUSE<br>
Resource Administrator:     
</div>
```

I want to extract data between `</h5>` and `</div>`.

Here is the regular expression that I've tried.

```
>Vendor Manager\(s\).*?<\/h5>(.*?)<\/
```

but it doesn't seems working.

any clue where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I believe the expression: `</h5>(.*?)</div>` should work fine providing you remove all the control tags such as **\n**, **\t**, etc, and excessive white-spaces from the string first. You can then use the html <br> tag within a String.split() method to separate the two.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for this job. This is exactly what XPath is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<\\/h5>(.|\\n)*?<\\/div>
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/WsYos4/1)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you shouldn't use regular expression for such tasks. Parse the HTML and use something like [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to extract a portion of it.

In case you still want to do it, try a pattern like this:

`<\/h5>(?s)(.*)<\/div>`